Python multiprocessing: How to release an unknown lock?
This is a question about multiprocessing execution getting stuck in combindation with a third-party package (suppose we call it package). Let's pretend this is my code
def work(arg):
    from package import f
    return f(arg)

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(8)
args = [ i for i in range(80) ]
results = pool.map(work, args)
for result in results: 
    result
pool.close()

In my particular case, this code runs fine until I use other functionality from package. If I modify the script like so:
def work(arg):
    from package import f
    return f(arg)

from package import SomeClass
obj = SomeClass()

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(8)
args = [ i for i in range(80) ]
results = pool.map(work, args) # execution gets stuck on this line
for result in results: 
    result
pool.close()

then it gets stuck on the commented line because f is not returning. Since this is a third-party package, I have imperfect knowledge of its inner workings, but I see no reason (using a reasonable amount of time) that SomeClass should depend on what happens in work. Since I don't need the object obj when I get to the multiprocessing, I want to delete it (or otherwise render ineffective its interaction with f) hoping that the map can execute. But it doesn't help
def work(arg):
    from package import f
    return f(arg)

from package import SomeClass
obj = SomeClass()
del obj
import gc
gc.collect()

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(8)
args = [ i for i in range(80) ]
results = pool.map(work, args) # execution still gets stuck on this line
for result in results: 
    result
pool.close()


Is there something I can do in reasonable time to find out what is causing map execution to get blocked?
I want to use brute force to get rid of the lock (or whatever it is in SomeClass preventing execution) after am done with obj. What are my options to achieve that?


Edit:
It works to execute the second function not in parallel:
def work(arg):
    from package import f
    return f(arg)

from package import SomeClass
obj = SomeClass()
obj = None
del obj
import gc
gc.collect()

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(8)
arg = 42
work(arg)  # execution work if I don't run it in parallel

Edit2:
Here is a minimal reproducible example.
from pyscf.pbc.gto import Cell
import numpy as np
from pyscf.pbc.dft import numint

# comment out the following 6 lines to allow work to return successfully.
cell1 = Cell()
cell1.a = "\n".join([f"{str(row).replace(',','').strip('[]')}" for row in np.eye(3)])
cell1.atom = "\n".join([f"C {str(row).replace(',','').strip('[]')}" for row in np.random.rand(3,3)])
cell1.build()
mf = cell1.RKS()
ao_value = numint.eval_ao(cell1, mf.grids.coords)
# comment out the preceeding 6 lines to allow work to return successfully.

cell2 = Cell()
cell2.a = "\n".join([f"{str(row).replace(',','').strip('[]')}" for row in np.eye(3)])
cell2.atom = "\n".join([f"C {str(row).replace(',','').strip('[]')}" for row in np.random.rand(3,3)])
cell2.build()

def work( cell ):
    grid_coords = np.random.rand(3, 3)
    print("gets stuck after this line...")
    ao = cell.pbc_eval_gto("GTOval_cart", grid_coords)
    print("...and before this line")
    return 1

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(1)
args = [ cell2 for I in np.arange(1) ]
results = pool.imap(work, args)
for result in results: I = result
pool.close()


Your latest code fragment will certainly work because you're not attempting any multiprocessing. You are however doing some odd things - e.g., creating a Pool and not closing it, setting obj to None then calling del. Notwithstanding these comments, the most likely issue is that the imported function f is not returning. You'll need to debug it in isolation

@SIGHUP I've changed the to remove the odd things. And yes. The function f doesn't return. Moreover, execution is getting stuck inside a context manager in some method that f depends on. All the threads enter that context manager, and none of them escape. (1) How can I determine what blocks execution, (2) how can I brute force undo the harms of constructing obj after am done with obj (as deleting obj doesn't do)? (3) Do you understand why the question is receiving down votes, such that I can improve it?

Can you make a [mcve], instead of an unknown "package"?

@MarkTolonen Please see above

Long story short, use multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') at the start of your script , this package uses openmp which doesn't support fork, also since it is using openmp then multiprocessing won't really give you a speed boost anyway

The problem is not a lock, there is no lock to release, openmp is submitting work to workers that don't exist after the fork, it simply doesn't support forking

FWIW you can just use a threadpool instead since the package is using extensions it is dropping the GIL
